# Solr 6 Setup with managed schema and cloud

Tags: solr

Dear Awesome SF community,

My question is about how to start with Solr 6 with dynamic/managed schema and SolrCloud.

I have used Solr 5 and 4.  There used be a command "solrctl", using solrctl, we can create instance directory and setup collection.

e.g.

solrctl instancedir --generate $SOLR_HOME/dyndoc

solrctl instancedir --create dyndoc $SOLR_HOME/dyndoc

solrctl collection --create dyndoc -s 1 -r 2

With solr 6, solrctl is gone.

Can someone give me a pointer on how to achieve the same.  (OR I need to use REST API)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solr utility is now named just `solr` and is bundled in `bin/solr` in the Solr archive you download.

```
$ bin/solr
Usage: solr COMMAND OPTIONS
   where COMMAND is one of: start, stop, restart, status, healthcheck, create, create_core, create_collection, delete, version, zk
```

Example for create_collection:

```
$ bin/solr create_collection -help

Usage: solr create_collection [-c collection] [-d confdir] [-n configName] [-shards #] [-replicationFactor #] [-p port]

  -c <collection>         Name of collection to create
```